# Use the value of a cell in a table as the argument to a function

Tags: list-manipulation, curated-data

I just got *Mathematica* from my school and I'm trying to learn the basics.

*How could I use the value of a cell in a table (as in Insert->Table) and pass it as an argument to a function whose value is displayed in another cell in the same table?*

For example, in my table displaying some chemistry data, my input and output cells would conceptually be something like this:

```
Gold   |  ElementData["CELL TO THE LEFT", "Specific Heat"]

Silver |  ElementData["CELL TO THE LEFT", "Specific Heat"]

Copper |  ElementData["CELL TO THE LEFT", "Specific Heat"]
```

This is kind of how it would work in a spreadsheet program.

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope you will realize very soon that *Mathematica* is not Excel. If you begin learning the basics by mimicking how you would do it in Excel, you are off to a very bad start.

Let us try to do it more in *Mathematica* style. First, we make a list of your elements

```
elms = {"Gold", "Silver", "Copper"}
```

Now, we make a function which takes an arbitrary element name and returns the specific heat. Then we apply (we *map* with `/@`) this function to every entry of your elements list

```
heats = Function[elm, ElementData[elm, "SpecificHeat"]] /@ elms
```

Now, we have to lists, one with the elements and one with the heats. Now, you can display them in a table if you like:

```
TableForm[{elms, heats}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

#### Edit:

Regarding your comment: I know what you are referring to, but a direct equivalence to when Excel refers to a column does not exist. However, there are million more ways once you got used to *Mathematica*. For instance, let's put everything we know until now into a function which takes an arbitrary list of elements and creates the table view you want. You'll see that it's only a combination of what I showed you above

```
create[elms_List] := 
 TableForm[
  Transpose[{elms, 
    Function[elm, ElementData[elm, "SpecificHeat"]] /@ elms}]];
```

Now we use this `create` function to make a dynamic list of as many elements you like

```
With[{allElms = ElementData[]},
 Manipulate[create[allElms[[1 ;; n]]], {n, 1, Length[allElms], 1}]
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Is there a way to make this dynamic? What if I didn't know what elements I was going to use before hand, but wanted to add them dynamically? Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: @DeoxNa See my updated answer.

Comment: That worked! Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps

```
Table[{j, ElementData[j, "SpecificHeat"]}, {j, {"Gold", "Silver", "Copper"}}] // TableForm
```

[image]

or

```
tableF = {#, ElementData[#, "SpecificHeat"]} &;
tableF /@ {"Gold", "Silver", "Copper"} // TableForm
(* same output *)
```

or

```
(* initialize a 3 by 2 table: *)
table = ConstantArray[0, {3, 2}]; 
(* set the first column to the three element names: *)
table[[All, 1]] = {"Gold", "Silver", "Copper"}; 
(* set the second column as a function of the first: *)
table[[All, 2]] =  ElementData[#, "SpecificHeat"] & /@ table[[All, 1]] ;
table // TableForm 
(* same output *)
```